# in R, how to load text lines containing newlines, and display them as multi-line output in mtext

Tags: r, newline

Suppose I create two strings, each of which contains newlines, and assign them to variables as shown below.

```
question_one<- 'What is your answer?\n\nYes\nNo\nMaybe'
question_two<- 'What is your reply?\n\nOne\nTwo\nThree'
```

Then `writeLines(question_one)` and `mtext(side=1, question_one)` output the question on 5 separate lines (the second of which is blank); this is exactly the output I am after.

What I can't do is, start with those two strings as the two lines in a 2-line text document, bring them into my R session by using something like

```
filename="/path/sample_questions.txt"
my_scanned_questions <- scan(filename, what="", sep="\r", allowEscapes=F)
```

and then use `mtext(side=1, my_scanned_questions[i])` to generate the output text of my ith question on 5 lines.

I have tried various combinations of `sep` values, different numbers (1,2,4) of backslashes in my .txt file, etc, `allowEscapes` as `T` and `F`, but the closest I can get is `mtext(side=1, my_scanned_questions[1])` outputs the string `'q1 What is your answer?\n\nYes\nNo\nMaybe'` on one display line.

I've had no better luck using `readLines` instead of scan.

Answer (score 0):

I created a text file with three lines of text in it [here](https://gist.github.com/corynissen/541100602ac4bc7b3dc6)

You need to replace the double backslashed newline with a single...

```
a <- readLines("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/corynissen/541100602ac4bc7b3dc6/raw/1adc16160a8a2aa705b7bbb3810723cc416079a1/a2.txt")
plot(1:10)
a <- gsub("\\\\n", "\n", a)
mtext(side=1, a[1])
```

[image]

Comment: ahh, you've helped me see I was ambiguous in my initial description. What I need is a text file where the first line is `What is your answer?\n\nYes\nNo\nMaybe` and the second line is `What is your reply?\n\nOne\nTwo\nThree` and i want to `scan` or `readLines` them in, and have the first question, which I initially referred to as `my_scanned_lines[1]` display (via mtext) on 5 display lines